# GetTempFileName() and proper file extensions

Tags: c#

I'm using GetTempFileName() in order to write bytes from a database to a temporary file. These files are normally PDF type, however, they can and do vary.

I'm running into an issue where attempting Process.Start(tempPath) throws an error because Windows cannot find an associated program with a .tmp file.

As opposed to writing a custom method that verifies the mime type and adjusts the file name as needed, is there any common/standard way to handle this .tmp file type in .NET?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that [Reed Copsey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501028/284240) on a related question helps to answer yours:

You can append the extension to the autogenerated temp-file:

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName() + ".pdf"; // Makes something like "C:\Temp\blah.tmp.pdf"

File.WriteAllBytes(filename, filedata);

var process = Process.Start(filename);
// Clean up our temporary file...
process.Exited += (s,e) => System.IO.File.Delete(filename);
```

Comment: Except now you're generating two files. One as `%temp%\<whatever>.tmp`, and another as `%temp%\<whatever>.tmp.pdf`. (Personally, I'd and use [`FindExecutable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and keep the clutter to a minimum.)

Comment: @BradChristie: yes, but the second is also created in the temp-directory and will deleted in `process.Exited`. The `GetTempFileName`-file has 0 bytes and there is no additional naming conflict.

Comment: But you're still not allowed more than 65535 files, and you're only deleting the renamed variation and not the original (though that can be changed easily in your lambda). I just feel like using two files is unnecessary when there's a shell method for it.